# Integrate SAML authentication for APIs developed in microservices

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, microservices, saml-2.0

I need to develop set of microservices (rest APIs) which is to be used by web and mobile client, the microservices are sitting behind API gateway, I've to integrate with SSO (using SAML) for user's authentication, I understand that SAML token to oAuth2 token conversion has to be done so that I can verify auth token at API gateway and handle authorization there itself, but the piece which is not clear to me is that who will take care of conversion of SAML token to oAuth2 token, is it IDP who provide this functionality out of box or do I need to built up something of my own?

One possible solution which I'm thinking of is

- User (from web/mobile) sign in via SSO
- Gets SAML response from IDP
- Send that SAML response to server to generate Auth Token
- Server gets request to generate auth token, looks for SAML response and validate it against IDP
- If SAML response is valid then generate auth token and send it back to client
- On subsequent API request from client the token is passed as header which API gateway validates

The thing is I'm bit reluctant to implement SAML and oAuth thingy myself and looking for some ready made solution but couldn't find any, can someone please suggest of any library solving this problem, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It feels like your approach is correct - it is the role of the Authorization Server (AS) to deal with SAML login integration for you. Only configuration changes should be needed, though of course you need to use an AS that supports SAML integration.

Your UIs and APIs will not need to know anything about SAML and will just use OAuth tokens. There should be zero code changes needed.

Most companies use an off the shelf AS - eg from a low cost cloud provider. My [Federated Logins Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2020/05/23/federation-logins/) summarises the process of integrating an IDP. The walkthrough uses AWS Cognito as the AS - and the IDP could be a SAML one.

Answer (score 0):

I maintain a microservice that sounds like it could help you - https://github.com/enterprise-oss/osso

Osso handles SAML configuration against a handful of IDP providers, normalizes payloads, and makes user resources available to you in an oauth 2.0 authorization code grant flow.

Osso mainly acts as an authentication server though - we don't currently have a way for your API gateway to verify an access token is (still) valid, but that would be pretty trivial for us to add, we'd be happy to consider it.